# Charged amounts with recurring_payment_profile_created and Initial Amount

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I've got a really quick question ;)

I have setup a recurring monthly profile to bill at $29.97/month, and I've set an initial amount of $29.97 to be charged immediately.

Is PayPal going to bill BOTH upon profile creation?  I am assuming NO, but I am receiving two IPN messages when I am testing, so I just want to make sure that when I go into a live environment the customer is not going to be charged Twice.

The First IPN Response is: 
recurring_payment_profile_created (with the initial amount charged) 
But then I receive another:  recurring_payment  Response as well.

Thanks for your help!
C.

Comment: I receive subscr_payment and subscr_signup and no recurring_payment_profile_created or recurring_payment. Do I maybe confuse some different types of payments?

Answer (score 0):

There would be 2 charges being processed.  If you are not wanting to have to charges processed right away, you would need to set your start date a month out when creating the profile.

Comment: Ok, I can set it a month out, that's not a problem.
My god PayPal's system for this stuff is confusing sometimes.